# Cumsum of previous values if conditions are met after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have unbalanced panel. Basically, someone will increase liquidity before decreasing that liquidity fully. I have groups (NF_TOKEN_ID). I want to first `groupby` and whenever `ACTION` is `DECREASE_LIQUIDITY` i want to replace the zero value with all the funds that have been withdrawn. This amount corresponds to however much has been added previously. So I will have to cumsum previous values if value from `ACTION` is `INCREASE_LIQUIDITY`. `cumsum` should only be applied to funds that have been added right before, not retrospectively.

My current df.

```
    BLOCK_TIMESTAMP NF_TOKEN_ID ACTION  LIQUIDITY   AMOUNT0_ADJUSTED    AMOUNT1_ADJUSTED
0   2023-01-19 11:43:23+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.0002500037479372e+16  0.0  999999.999999
1   2023-01-21 10:08:35+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.0002500037479372e+16  0.0 0.0
2   2023-01-23 17:43:23+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.9999500037496876e+16  1000000.0   0.0
3   2023-01-28 21:42:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.9999500037496876e+16  0.0 0.0
4   2023-01-31 09:20:11+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.001358136187257e+16   0.0 1000553.996968
5   2023-02-05 14:19:11+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.001358136187257e+16   0.0 0.0
6   2023-02-06 16:00:59+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.9510177985927736e+16  900000.0    1075372.476351
7   2023-02-11 16:21:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.9510177985927736e+16  0.0 0.0
8   2023-02-11 18:17:47+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.999900007499375e+16   2000000.0   0.0
9   2023-02-13 08:42:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.999900007499375e+16   0.0 0.0
10  2023-02-16 23:39:11+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  6.000384593243181e+16   3000267.297679  0.0
11  2023-02-18 13:02:47+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.000210525110979e+16   1000130.263937  0.0
64  2023-01-19 11:52:47+00:00   417520.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.5233876511464717e+21  2360900.644245  17981.537918728
65  2023-01-19 11:52:47+00:00   417520.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.5233876511464717e+21  0.0 0.0
66  2023-01-19 11:52:59+00:00   417521.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1e+19   0.05981737761   0.05981737761
81  2023-01-19 11:54:35+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  17130998133876.0    49.99712    0.02400335355
82  2023-01-23 07:29:23+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  28028281686564.0    121.373999  0.01412890286
83  2023-01-23 17:34:35+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  9508091561328.0 39.513265   0.00581565507
84  2023-01-25 00:55:47+00:00   417537.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  54667371381768.0    0.0 0.0
```

Desired df

```
    BLOCK_TIMESTAMP NF_TOKEN_ID ACTION  LIQUIDITY   AMOUNT0_ADJUSTED    AMOUNT1_ADJUSTED
0   2023-01-19 11:43:23+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.0002500037479372e+16  0.0  999999.999999
1   2023-01-21 10:08:35+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.0002500037479372e+16  0.0  999999.999999
2   2023-01-23 17:43:23+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.9999500037496876e+16  1000000.0   0.0
3   2023-01-28 21:42:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.9999500037496876e+16  1000000.0   0.0
4   2023-01-31 09:20:11+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.001358136187257e+16   0.0 1000553.996968
5   2023-02-05 14:19:11+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.001358136187257e+16   0.0 1000553.996968
6   2023-02-06 16:00:59+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.9510177985927736e+16  900000.0    1075372.476351
7   2023-02-11 16:21:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.9510177985927736e+16  900000.0    1075372.476351
8   2023-02-11 18:17:47+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.999900007499375e+16   2000000.0   0.0
9   2023-02-13 08:42:47+00:00   417467.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  3.999900007499375e+16   2000000.0   0.0
10  2023-02-16 23:39:11+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  6.000384593243181e+16   3000267.297679  0.0
11  2023-02-18 13:02:47+00:00   417467.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  2.000210525110979e+16   1000130.263937  0.0
64  2023-01-19 11:52:47+00:00   417520.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.5233876511464717e+21  2360900.644245  17981.537918728
65  2023-01-19 11:52:47+00:00   417520.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  1.5233876511464717e+21  2360900.644245  17981.537918728
66  2023-01-19 11:52:59+00:00   417521.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  1e+19   0.05981737761   0.05981737761
81  2023-01-19 11:54:35+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  17130998133876.0    49.99712    0.02400335355
82  2023-01-23 07:29:23+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  28028281686564.0    121.373999  0.01412890286
83  2023-01-23 17:34:35+00:00   417537.0    INCREASE_LIQUIDITY  9508091561328.0     39.513265   0.00581565507
84  2023-01-25 00:55:47+00:00   417537.0    DECREASE_LIQUIDITY  54667371381768.0    210.884384  0.04394791148
```

Comment: Your data seem to contain unnecessary information. Usually it can go like this: `df['value_to_sum'].mul(df['condition_value'].eq(SOMETHING)).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()`.

Comment: it isnt unnecessary data, it's only bc i am showing only part of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
cols = ['AMOUNT0_ADJUSTED', 'AMOUNT1_ADJUSTED']
decl = df['ACTION'] == 'DECREASE_LIQUIDITY'

df.loc[decl, cols] = -(df.groupby(['NF_TOKEN_ID', decl.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()])
                       [cols].cumsum()[decl])
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['NF_TOKEN_ID', 'ACTION'] + cols]

    NF_TOKEN_ID              ACTION  AMOUNT0_ADJUSTED  AMOUNT1_ADJUSTED
0      417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      0.000000e+00      1.000000e+06
1      417467.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -0.000000e+00     -1.000000e+06
2      417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      1.000000e+06      0.000000e+00
3      417467.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -1.000000e+06     -0.000000e+00
4      417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      0.000000e+00      1.000554e+06
5      417467.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -0.000000e+00     -1.000554e+06
6      417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      9.000000e+05      1.075372e+06
7      417467.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -9.000000e+05     -1.075372e+06
8      417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      2.000000e+06      0.000000e+00
9      417467.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -2.000000e+06     -0.000000e+00
10     417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      3.000267e+06      0.000000e+00
11     417467.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      1.000130e+06      0.000000e+00
64     417520.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      2.360901e+06      1.798154e+04
65     417520.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -2.360901e+06     -1.798154e+04
66     417521.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      5.981738e-02      5.981738e-02
81     417537.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      4.999712e+01      2.400335e-02
82     417537.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      1.213740e+02      1.412890e-02
83     417537.0  INCREASE_LIQUIDITY      3.951326e+01      5.815655e-03
84     417537.0  DECREASE_LIQUIDITY     -2.108844e+02     -4.394791e-02
```

**EDIT**

> How do I set the values to negative when ACTION is DECREASE_LIQUIDITY?

Comment: one more quick quetsion. how do i set the values to negative? when ACTION is DECREASE_LIQUIDITY?

Comment: Like `-210.884384` instead of `210.884384`?

Comment: yes, basically i want the values to be negative since it's withdrawing funds. sorry i forgot to mention.